# Video Codec with custom information

Tags: video, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, codec

I must include around one video frame(i must have 1 frame = 1 played frame in client) some text data.
Example: frame encode time with miliseconds, HH:MM:SS:MS.
But i don't know any video codec with i can include custom data to frame.

I will save from rasppery pi camera module video with this information.

Any video codec support add custom info for each  play frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codec won't include this information, but the **container** format can.

Some containers, like Matroska (MKV), support subtitle streams and others.  It's entirely possible for you to put arbitrary text data in them.  Alternatively, you should be able to create your own arbitrary stream data and use it in a flexible container like Matroska.

If all you really need is a timestamp, I'm sure there are existing formats that do this, similar to the way the Broadcast Waveform (BWF) works.  See also:  http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/350623-timestamps-video-container-codecs